# How to create true or false checkbox in Yii2?

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I have a problem here. In my `ActiveForm` I need to create a simple checkbox (which has to be a boolean value (0 - if the item was unpaid and 1 - if it was paid).

I've created in my `view` file a checkbox like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sign')->checkboxList([
    '' => '',
]); ?>
```

I thought that if I will mark the checkbox it will automatically will change to 1 (because in the database the value was set was `boolean`), but now it's writing that `it must be an integer`. When I'm deleting my rule and submitting my form, that value in the database is `NULL`.

So could anyone tell me how to do a checkbox, which if I would mark it, the value in the database would be 1, otherwise - 0? Thank you for any help..

Comment: Changing the db column type to integer (or tinyint) is not an option? That's how I would do it

Comment: The db column type is `tinyint`, but when I mark the checkbox it says that it has to be an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only 1 option, instead of `checkboxlist`, try `checkbox`:

```
$form->field($model, 'sign')->checkbox();
```